# why "storage size of 'array' isn't constant"

Tags: c, static

i am new to C.Last week, I learn to use array to solve problems. I find that when the number of array is too large, like 1024*1024, it will show error. Some people suggest me using static to solve it, but this error(title) makes me more confusing. I think i have defined the arguments, and it should be constant. But it is not. I could not understand.

Summary:

1. why this error happens?
2. why a constant is not a constant in C?
3. how could i solve it without using a ture constant,like 5000?
4. what function can take the place of static to storage large array?

this is the text code, showing the same error

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 500;
    static int arr[num] = {0};
    printf("%d",arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft compiler? MSVC does not support variable sized arrays. Try `static int arr[500];` instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `num` is not a constant value. You cannot create a static object if the size is not known at compile time.

Comment: the problem you have is that `num` is initialized *after* `arr[num]`. if you want it flexible, use malloc instead >   `int num = 500; int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*num); ... free(arr);`

Comment: @kaylum Now I am using vs code,g++. I know your code is right, but I want it flexible. Always change the value of num may be boring and error-prone.

Comment: @Gerhardh if I understand correctly, the value of num is unknown when using 
static int arr[num], which means we do not know it is 500 or another number. (sorry, I am not a native English speaker, maybe it is confusing)

Comment: @AndersK Do you mean that the 'static int' function is run before declaring the value of num? Mr.dbush's answer suggests I coding '#define NUM 500', and it's right. Maybe it is the order question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this error happens?

Objects with *static storage duration* are instantiated (have memory set aside for them) before the program begins execution; that means the size of the `arr` has to be known at compile time.  Even though we have an initializer for `num`, that's not the same thing as the value `num` being known at compile time; `num` doesn't *exist* until after the program begins execution.

Arrays declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword have to be declared with a size that's a *constant expression* - either an integer constant like `1024`, a `sizeof` expression like `sizeof (some-type)` or `sizeof some-expression`, an arithmetic expression involving either of the previous (such as `1024*1024` or `5000 * sizeof (int)`), or a macro that expands to any of the above.  Or they can be declared without a size and the size is taken from the number of elements in the initializer.

> why a constant is not a constant in C?

`500` is a constant - `num` is not.  Again, `num` doesn't exist until run time, but the size of `arr` has to be known *before* run time.  Adding the `const` keyword such as

```
const int num = 500;
```

doesn't help - all that `const` does is tell the compiler to yell at you if you try to assign a new value to `num`.  It doesn't make `num` a *constant expression* (in C, anyway - in C++ it does).

> how could i solve it without using a ture constant,like 5000?

At this point, you're pretty much limited to using dynamic memory.

> what function can take the place of static to storage large array?

Use either `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate space for the array at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
  size_t num = 500; // or whatever value you ultimately need

  /**
   * Dynamically allocate enough space for "num" objects of type "int". 
   * 
   * calloc will zero out the allocated memory (malloc does not).
   *
   * calloc will return NULL if it cannot satisfy the request, so we
   * want to make sure "arr" isn't NULL before trying to use it. 
   * 
   * The type of the *expression* "*arr" is "int", so "sizeof *arr" == "sizeof (int)"
   */
  int *arr = calloc( num, sizeof *arr ); 
                                         
  if ( arr ) 
  {
    printf( "%d\n", arr[0] );

    /**
     * Deallocate "arr" when you're done with it
     */
    free( arr );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A big advantage of using dynamic memory like this is that you can resize the array as necessary using `realloc` - can't do that with fixed-sized arrays (`static` or not).

As of C99, you can declare arrays with runtime variables as the size:

```
int num = 500;
int arr[num];
```

These are called *variable length arrays* and work just fine (in most C99 and later implementations), but because their size isn't known until runtime they cannot be declared `static` or at file scope, and they can't be declared with any initializers.  Like other `auto` arrays, they can't be arbitrarily large.  And despite their name, they cannot be resized once defined - the "variable" in "variable length" just means their size can be different each time they are instantiated.

Comment: you are right, I have got it. A small bug should be pointed, maybe we should change the ''int *arr = calloc( num, sizeof *arr );''  to  ''int *arr =(int *)calloc(num, sizeof(50)); '', in vs code,g++ , the former show error--invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @hlame_mastar: Why are you building C code with a C++ compiler?  The languages differ in some key aspects, and this is one of them. C allows for direct assignment of `void *` to other pointer types, C++ does not.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand, I will change the compiler. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An array with *static storage duration*, i.e. one defined either at file scope or with the `static` keyword, **must** have a size that is a compile time constant.  The value of a variable is not a compile time constant which is why you're getting the error.

Declaring the variable in question as `const` also doesn't qualify because it just means that the variable can't be modified, not that it's a compile time constant.

What you can do is use a preprocessor symbol for a constant.  This will get substituted in before the compiler runs.

```
#define NUM 500

static int arr[NUM] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

static storage duration arrays size has to be the constant expression C17 6.7.6.2/2).

From the C standard:

> An integer constant  expression shall  have  integer  type  and  shall
> only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants,   enumeration constants,   character   constants,sizeof expressions  whose  results
> are  integer  constants,  and  floating  constants  that  are  the
> immediate operands of casts.Cast operators in an integer constant
> expression shall only convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,
> except  as  part  of  an  operand  to  the sizeof operator.

As you see const integer variables are not listed there and they can't be considered as constant expressions.

examples:

```
#define SIZE 300

int x = 500;
int a[SIZE];
int b[SIZE+ 'a'];
int c[SIZE + sizeof(x)];

/* and even most modern compilers will accept it*/

int d[SIZE + sizeof(x) + (size_t)sqrt(sizeof(c))];
```

Comment: The relevant part to quote is C17 6.7.6.2/2.

Comment: @Lundin First sentence. But I believe that confusion comes from the `const` variables not being considered as constant expressions

Comment: It explicitly says "If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type." And that's it. The OP is trying to declare a VLA with `static`, which isn't valid C.